# Can a painted wall be resurfaced with mud to remove texture without flaking

Tags: drywall, drywall-mud

Can a painted wall be resurfaced with mud to remove texture without flaking down the road?

Has anyone had this done successfully?

I have textured walls and want to make them flat. Contractor states they will apply 3 layers of mud. I'm asking what they will do to prep the walls ... wink wink

Even with good prep, will this succeed?

Comment: Asking what prep steps they'll take seems like a very reasonable question to ask. Even if you _don't_ think they're trying to scam you.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this done succesfully.  prep included de-greasing and key sanding  They used diamond veneer plaster (that is "hot" plaster) for the finish.

This was a ceiling.

Answer (score 1):

Many homes in my area are built with some type of texture on the walls.

Often new owners want the walls to be smooth. Recoating or "floating" the surface with drywall compound is the common method to make a wall smooth. Two coats is minimal. What is done as prep depends on the condition of the wall to be floated. This can be extensive. Cleaning, scraping, sanding and such to nothing at all if the wall is clean and free of peeling paint.

I have never encountered an issue of the new compound flaking. If your contractor is recommending 3 coats, he is not looking to get out easy. I'd be confident.